# How to make a link of a button inside a servlet

Tags: servlets, button, methods, call

I have a login page which leads to a servlet where I check and validate the login and I need to "paint" a web depending on some data of the user logged.
The page must be the same, but the menu should have some different options.

**Now the problem is** that I'm trying to write the page in a String **inside** the servlet, to make it more dynamic, and i need to put a button or link or something which calls to my method "desconectar" (logout)

Here is a piece of code and, I imagine you can see the problem, i cannot write "desconectar();" between que onclick quotes.

```
        String cadenaout = "<html><head><title>Servlet InitServlet</title>";
        cadenaout += "</head><body><h1>Servlet InitServlet at " + request.getContextPath() + "</h1>";
        cadenaout += "<button onclick=\"  \" value=\" Desconectar \"/>";
        cadenaout += "</body></html>";
        out.println(cadenaout);
```

Any Ideas or suggestions?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: My suggestion is to not write your HTML inside the servlet but instead use `jsp`s.

Comment: I tried but the problem I had before was that I tried to invalidate session inside the onclick="" but it didn't waited until i clicked the button, it invitalidates the session from the moment the web was loaded.

Answer (score 0):

i dont get this "it invitalidates the session from the moment the web was loaded", can you elaborate a little bit? Actually, i dont get the whole perspective.

- Do you want to do a logout servlet?
  If you want a logout servlet i don't think javascript is of any use, but again please elaborate on the problem
- Why you say " i cannot write 'desconectar();' "? You should import the javascript file in which you have your function, e.g.

  cadenaout += "<script type='text/javascript'
    src='../js/scriptFile.js'></script>";

  cadenaout += "<button onclick='desconectar();' 
    value=' Desconectar '/>";

Comment: At the end I decided to use a link and another servlet to do the function

Answer (score 0):

To create button in servlet page, follow this

```
out.print("<br><a href=\"#\"><button type=\"button\">Edu Analytics</button></a>");
```